# Custom eclipse builder

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to create custom builder, that will do something. I have looked across a lot of docs and still have troubles with getting it work. I suppose that I misunderstand something.

I am guided by [this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/FAQ/How_do_I_implement_an_Eclipse_builder%3F).

1) I have created a plugin project.

2) Manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: EScript_Builder
Bundle-SymbolicName: eScript_Builder; singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime, org.eclipse.core.resources
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
```

3) Plugin.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>
    <extension 
         id="Builder" 
         name="eScript Builder" 
         point="org.eclipse.core.resources.builders">
        <builder>
            <run class="escript_builder.Builder">
                <parameter name="optimize" value="true"/>
                <parameter name="comment" value="escript Builder"/>
            </run>
        </builder>
    </extension>
</plugin>
```

4) Builder:

```
public class Builder extends IncrementalProjectBuilder
{

    @Override
    protected IProject[] build(int kind, Map<String, String> args, IProgressMonitor monitor) throws CoreException
    {
        IProject project = getProject();
        System.out.println(project.getFullPath());
        File f = new File("D:" + File.separator + "hurray!"); //Check that builder worked
        try
        {
            f.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

After that, I have added

```xml
<buildCommand>
  <name>escript_builder.Builder</name> 
  <arguments> </arguments>
</buildCommand>
```

to `.project` of a test application, but if I go to project->properties->builders it is said "Missing builder(escript_builder.Builder)".
Also, I tried to export it as plugin and do project->properties->builders->new->program, but during build got an exception "escript_builder.Builder is not a valid win32 application".

Thank You for any help or guidance!

Comment: project->properties->builders->new->program is to run an external program as a builder. For your type of builder your plugin must be installed.

Answer (score 1):

Your builder id is 'eScript_Builder.Builder', not 'escript_builder.Builder' (different case, the first part is the plugin id). So the .project entry should be

```xml
<buildCommand>
  <name>eScript_Builder.Builder</name> 
  <arguments> </arguments>
</buildCommand>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. Thank You, @greg-449.

I have exported my plugin, put it into the "plugin" directory of Eclipse, launched eclipse with `-clean` argument and after that it worked.